# Multiple JWPlayers on Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, jwplayer

I have a Wordpress site that has a large photo slider for the header.  Within that slider, I have buttons to launch videos corresponding to the current image.  These are being set by custom tags within multiple posts.  All the data is being passed correctly (based off of looking at the source code), however, I can only get 1 video to play while the other 2 (3 total) just appear black and won't play anything at all.
Here is my embed code:

```
<div id="video-block'.$videoID.'" class="video-block-player hide">
          <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="'.$video_width[0].'" height="'.$video_height[0].'" id="video'.$videoID.'" name="video'.$videoID.'">
            <param name="movie'.$videoID.'" value="player.swf">
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
            <param name="flashvars" value="'.$video_link[0].'&autostart=true&icons=false&mute=true">
            <embed
              type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
              id="video'.$videoID.'"
              name="video'.$videoID.'"
              src="player.swf"
              width="'.$video_width[0].'"
              height="'.$video_height[0].'"
              bgcolor="undefined"
              allowscriptaccess="always"
              allowfullscreen="true"
              wmode="transparent"
              flashvars="file='.$video_link[0].'&autostart=true&icons=false&mute=true"
            />
          </object>
          </div>
```

The $videoID is being set dynamically to ensure that elements like the div id's are unique, all other variables are being set and pulled from custom tags (and again, appear correct when I view source).
Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I might do to get multiple video players working on a single page?  (Please note that I am using JWPlayer, but am not forced to use it if someone has a better solution, but that this embed code is already being launched from within another Plug-In [SlidePress] so plug-in options may not be the best solution.)

Thanks in advance for any and all help!
J

Answer (score 0):

Try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what's loading and not loading and what errors you get.